# How do I compress files in-place?

Tags: command-line, tar, disk-usage, compression, gzip

I have a machine with 90% hard-disk usage.  I want to compress its 500+ log files into a smaller new file. However, the hard disk is too small to keep both the original files and the compressed ones.

So what I need is to compress all log files into a single new file one by one, deleting each original once compressed.

How can I do that in Linux?

Comment: Duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/378230

Answer (score 26):

`gzip` or `bzip2` will compress the file and remove the non-compressed one automatically (this is their default behaviour).

However, keep in mind that while the compressing process, both files will exists.

If you want to compress log files (ie: files containing text), you may prefer `bzip2`, since it has a better ratio for text files.

```
bzip2 -9 myfile       # will produce myfile.bz2
```

Comparison and examples:

```
$ ls -l myfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 apaul apaul 585999 29 april 10:09 myfile

$ bzip2 -9 myfile

$ ls -l myfile*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 apaul apaul 115780 29 april 10:09 myfile.bz2

$ bunzip2 myfile.bz2

$ gzip -9 myfile

$ ls -l myfile*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 apaul apaul 146234 29 april 10:09 myfile.gz
```

**UPDATE** as @Jjoao told me in a comment, interestingly, `xz` seems to have a best ratio on plain files with its default options:

```
$ xz -9 myfile

$ ls -l myfile*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 apaul apaul 109384 29 april 10:09 myfile.xz
```

For more informations, here is an interesting benchmark for different tools: http://binfalse.de/2011/04/04/comparison-of-compression/

For the example above, I use `-9` for a best compression ratio, but if the time needed to compress data is more important than the ratio, you'd better not use it (use a lower option, ie `-1`, or something between).

Comment: +1; Just curious: could you add a `xz myfile` ?

Comment: @JJoao thanks! It's interesting, I'm not used to use `xz`, but I'll consider it now. See the update of my post.

Comment: Please don't do `xz -9`. It greatly increases the memory required for compression/decompression, without significantly improving the compression ratio. The manpage even says (emphasis theirs) "Specifically, **it's not a good idea to blindly use -9  for  everything** like it often is with gzip(1) and bzip2(1)". The default `xz -6` is good enough, and even `xz -0`/`xz -1` usually compress better than `gzip -9`.

Comment: @user49740 you're right. I rarely use `-9`, but I used it here since I wanted to make some kind of benchmark for compression ratio "on the same scale". But once again, you're totally right: it's a bad idea to blindly use `-9`.

Answer (score 26):

I figured out a tar solution by myself.
It deletes single file after compressed it into the target file.
The compressing speed is not quite fast, though. The command looks like:

```
tar -zcvf my_log.tar.gz *.log --remove-files
```

Comment: Good 'ol tar. +1

Comment: # you can also just point to the log directory  ('log' being the log directory containing the logfiles)

```tar --remove-files -zcvf my_log.tar.gz log```

Answer (score 3):

when you use io redirection in bash with `>`, the original file will be empty before write new data.

there is a command dd that can overwrite some content of the file instead of empty the file before writing, so following command may work:

```bsh
gzip -c some-file | dd conv=notrunc of=some-file
```

mostly, compressed data are smaller than original data.
when gzip read first N bytes, it only output M bytes where M < N,
so one can safely overwrites first M bytes
of original file with compressed data,
and leave data after first N bytes not changed.

but there will be data after the end of gzip.

however, if dd write faster than gzip, i do not know what will happen.

---

or you can map a file to a block device by losetup.
for block device, writing operation will not empty the original data.

```bsh
loop_device=$(losetup -f--show some-file)
gzip -c $loop_device > $loop_device
```

Answer (score 2):

In complement to @apaul, I emphasize that compressing files individually

```
 bzip2 *.log.*
```

(replace bzip2 by gzip, xz, or what ever your favorite file zip is)
may be important:

This way you can still see (`bzcat file.bz2`), search (`bzgrep file.bz2`), edit (`vi file.bz2`) the compressed file 
and remove the older ones when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do this on the BSD-version of tar. In this case, the --remove-files option is not available. What I ended up doing (and worked) was:

```
find folder_to_tar -type f -exec tar --append --file=output_tar_file.tar {} \; -exec rm -v {} \;
```

Comment: By the way, the BSD version is what you get by default if you happen to be using MacOS